# md5/sha1 hashing large files

Tags: linux, bash, hash

I have over 1/2 million files to hash over multiple folders
An md5/crc hashing is taking too long some files are 1GB ~ 11Gb in size
Im thinking of just hashing part of the file using head

So the below works when it comes to hashing finding and hashing everything.

```
find . -type f -exec sha1sum {} \;
```

Im just sure how to take this a step further and just do hash for the first say 256kB of the file e.g

```
find . -type f -exec head -c 256kB | sha1sum
```

Not sure if head is okay to use in this instance of would dd be better?
The above command doesn't work so looking for ideas on how I can do this

I would like the output to be the same as what is seen in a native md5sum e.g in the below format (going to a text file)

```
<Hash>  <file name>
```

Im not sure if the above is possible with a single line or will a for/do loop need to be used..... Performance is key using bash on RHEL6

Comment: its the pipe that is throwing your process off. Put your `head .. | sha1sum` in a script. Also add a "$@" as an arg to head. Good luck.

Comment: Doesn't this partly abrogate the use of a hash? Namely that if a few bytes change - regardless of their position - the hash changes?

Comment: Consider using `GNU Parallel` to get the job done using all those lovely cores you paid for that are sitting idle. It's easy, just send a list of the commands you would have run into `parallel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unclear where your limitation is. Do you have a slow disk or a slow CPU?

If your disk is not the limitation, you are probably limited by using a single core. GNU Parallel can help with that:

```
find . -type f | parallel -X sha256sum
```

If the limitation is disk I/O, then your idea of `head` makes perfect sense:

```
sha() {
   tail -c 1M "$1" | sha256sum | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$a=shift} s/-/$a/' "$1";
}
export -f sha
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -j10 --tag sha
```

The optimal value of `-j10` depends on your disk system, so try adjusting it until you find the optimal value (which can be as low as `-j1`).

Comment: yes disk i/o is an issue in my case, Most of the files are archived on slow backed storage.  Reading from this especially when a full hash is needed is very slow.  As an example a 2.5TB folder took 6.5 days to full hash every file (>600K files) Hence the need for a solution which will give "some" confidence that the files are in order after a copy

Comment: I have seen backend storage that has extremely slow seek times, but pretty fast reading speeds (think tape stations robots and similar). Depending on whether it is seeking it may still be faster to parallelize. The only way to know for sure is to try.

Comment: I just understood now that you need confidence of a copying. For that I will highly recommend using `tail` instead of `head`: that way you will catch if only the start of a big file was copied.

Comment: What exactly is the "perl -pe" doing here it only seems to work with this in place

Comment: It replaces - in the output from sha256sum with $1 (i.e. the filename)

Comment: Your sha function is using the first argument (filename) but your parallel - j10 sha seem not to give the function any parameter I would expect it to be parallel - j10 sha <filename>?    Also I don't have parallel will be using xargs -P

Comment: Can I ask you to see if I have covered your reason for not installing GNU Parallel on: http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html ? GNU Parallel defaults to adding {} to the command line, so it becomes sha <filename>. Since you _will_ be using the output, then using xargs -P is dangerous as it mixes the output: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-xargs-AND-GNU-Parallel

Comment: Secure site so getting binaries installed that are not part of the build is difficult, also if there is a &  in the filename the script fails any way to fix the regex at the end

Comment: If you are allowed to run your own script, you do not need to have GNU Parallel installed for you: You can do it yourself. Code adapted to deal with file names containing any character except \0 (NUL).