# What is the fastest way to generate MD5 code for a huge (140 GB) tar file in Fedora?

Tags: md5, fedora, md5sum, md5-file

Recently I downloaded a big (140 GB) tar file and it has an MD5 code to verify the downloaded version.

I used **md5sum filename** to generate MD5 code and compare it with the original one. But, it seems that I should wait for a long time.

Is there a *faster* way to generate MD5 code for a big file in Fedora?

Comment: have a look at this, this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817057/md5-sha1-hashing-large-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using SSD,  your hard drive will be only able to read at about 30M/s.

So for a 140 000MB file size, you have already something like 1h and a half just to read the file.

Now add that there is some process on your computer running, i guess that your "long time" can be something like 2 hours.

Unless switching of storage support for a faster one (SSD, USB), there's nothing much you can do.

Now if md5sum take 10h, i guess it's possible you can find better.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, 2 hours is not a big headache. I can wait and pray.